# Контейнер с товарами WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Стоит задача сделать комплектный товар с помощью Сгруппированный товар и плагинами WPC Product Bundles for WooCommerce и YITH WooCommerce Product Bundles Premium все они передают в чек по мимо товаров включающих в комплект и еще сам комплект с ценой 0 руб для налоговой так не пойдет, стоит для оплаты yandex kassa 2.0 Как сделать типа контейнера с товарами и при добавлении его просто в корзину добавлялись товары?

Answer (score 0):

Смог сделать с помощью плагина 
WPC Grouped Product for WooCommerce

Comment: Так не интересно...